# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, unicode, python-2.x

I'm facing some trouble with Unicode. I'm a beginner in programming, so I couldn't understand the other answers related to this issue here.

**TraceBack**

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/django/django_project/learn/views.py" in index
  19.         if str(get_one_phrasalverb) not in cannot_be_random:

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /learn/keep-from/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Problematic code part**

```
cannot_be_random = request.session.get('cannot_be_random')

if str(get_one_phrasalverb) not in cannot_be_random:
     cannot_be_random.append(str(get_one_phrasalverb))
     request.session['cannot_be_random'] = cannot_be_random
```

Please tell me if some part of the code or part of the traceback is missing.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is inside `str(get_one_phrasalverb)`. The error says that `get_one_phrasalverb` could not be converted to `str` with `ascii` encoding.

So you need to know the encoding of `get_one_phrasalverb` first, if the encoding is `utf8`, you could use `get_one_phrasalverb.encode('utf8')` instead of `str(get_one_phrasalverb)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I'm getting:  object has no attribute 'encode'. Do you know what It could be?

Comment: what is the type of `get_one_phrasalverb`, you could print it with `type(get_one_phrasalverb)`

Comment: Since its type is not unicode, you need to do encode inside `PhrasalVerb`'s `__str__` or `__repr__` method

Comment: If `self.name` is a string, you could do it